# How to change theme dynamically in mvc3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I want to change the theme of my web page on user selection
I am using MVC3.
My idea is to include various style sheets inside the Content folder and let the _layout.cshtml file decide which css file to call on user selection
At present all i can do is include a  single  tag which is reflected on all the pages
I want the view to be the same but the style sheets should change on selection.

I tried this code inside _Layout.cshtml:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadjscssfile(filename) {
        var fileref = document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
```

Inside Body tag:

```
<select>
        <option onclick="loadjscssfile("@Url.Content("~/Content/Site1.css")")">Theme1</option>
        <option onclick="loadjscssfile("@Url.Content("~/Content/Site2.css")")">Theme2</option>
        </select>
```

But this also does not work:(
Please help me.I am new to MVC3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post should help you:

[ASP.NET MVC Theme Supported Razor View Engine](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/asp-dot-net-mvc-theme-supported-razor-view-engine)

**UPDATE:**
This sample won't compile with mvc3. You should do some "find and replace" for

```
ViewModel.Title -> ViewBag.Title
ViewModel.Message -> ViewBag.Message
ViewModel.PasswordLength -> ViewBag.PasswordLength

return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath), this, incompletMatch); -> return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath), this);
```

Comment: hi,i have already gone through this link and also downloaded the entire zip file but once i run it is giving me error as:ViewModel does not exists in the current context and i have no idea about ViewModels

Comment: If you need more powerful themming you can also try my CavemanTools Mvc toolkit (nuget it). See how to use themes here https://bitbucket.org/sapiensworks/caveman-tools/wiki/Themes

Comment: Updated answer. After the edit compile and works on my machine with MVC3

Comment: @Iridio Hi All errors are resolved except one:
Inside FindPartialView()
return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath), this);

Comment: if you change to return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath), this); in line 96 and 125 of ThemeableVirtualPathProviderViewEngine.cs, it should works. At least works for me

Comment: @Iridio hey thanx i got it...its working!!!
jus wanted to confirm whether this is the only method through which this can be performed or there is any other simpler way coz it looks a bit complex

Comment: If you want to create a module that you can reuse in other projects I don't think that you can get something with a lot less lines of code imo.

Comment: @Iridio your suggestions also worked for me.. but another question is there a way that instead of the user clicks the theme of choice it automatically changes from one theme to another at a given time period..?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you keep one stylesheet and only changes a class on your body tag

```
<body class="red|blue">
    //your content
</body>
```

and inside your style sheet you only add different styles to each selector

```
.red{
    background-color: red;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply But how should i change the Color dynamically whethr i should include some switch logic inside the controller?